# Change dtype policy of tensorflow saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a model using `tensorflow 2.2.0` with a `mixed_float16` policy. Training and evaluation of the model went fine, but now the model cannot be evaluated on devices that do not support `mixed_float16`, e.g. older GPUs or CPUs.

For example, when loading the model on a computer without GPU I get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'MaxPool3D' used by {{node model/max_pooling3d/MaxPool3D}} with these attrs: [ksize=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME", T=DT_HALF, data_format="NDHWC", strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]]
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
  device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]

     [[model/max_pooling3d/MaxPool3D]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_19293]
```

I have tried to set the TensorFlow policy locally before loading the model via

```
policy = tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.Policy("float32")
tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy(policy)
```

Unfortunately, that does not change the dtype of the model.

Is there anyway to change the dtype of a changed model? Or to somehow save the model to allow it to automatically choose for float32 when float16 is not available?

I've also tried to look into using `TFLite` for this purpose, but the optimization there can also not be done due to issues with the model being saved as in mixed precision format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried to save the weights and for model and then load them into a newly constructed model, but that didn't work.
However, directly copying the weights from the trained model to a new model directly. In short, something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
trained_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(/model/path)

# Function to create the model architecture without trained weights
# Make sure that this model is not created using a mixed precision policy!
new_model = create_model()

new_model.set_weight(trained_mode.get_weights())
```

The `new_model` can then be used on CPU as well.

Comment: Ah, so I just have a `mixed_precision` parameter on my `create_model` function and first I make one with `True`, train that model, call `create_model` with `False` and copy the weights in. But doesn't `tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy("mixed_float16")` have side effects in a function? So I should either always set the policy or set it back to `"float32"` after use. Right?